# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I (erroneously) setup a corporate Ubuntu server nearly three years ago with Ubuntu 9.04, instead of the 8.x LTS. What's the best path for me to take now in order to get this server to an LTS based version (10.04 LTS)?

TIA - Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step "from 9.04 to 9.10":

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Second step "from 9.10 to 10.04":

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades:

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts
```

Start upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Comment: Many thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for. I should have dug into the manuals better before asking the question - my apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

For guidance, see the [UpdateNotes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes) page on the Ubuntu Documentation site, which tells you which versions you can upgrade from and to, and provides detailed instructions on doing so.

In your case [9.04 > 9.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KarmicUpgrades) and then [9.10 > 10.04 LTS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades).

Comment: Many thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for.